# How to change the data for x-axis and y-axis in sns.distplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I get a `pd.series` as follows:

```
train_df['area'] 

0     68.06
1    125.55
2    132.00
3     57.00
4    129.00
5    223.35
6     78.94
7     76.00
Name: area, dtype: float64
```

And I draw the `sns.distplot()` of it, but I get a plot as follows:

[image: sns.distplot]

BUT, what I really want is that **x-axis** and **y-axis** should be [0, 1,...,7] and [40, 60,..., 240].
I am wondering how to fix it?
.
If not mind, could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use plt's axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# pass ax here
sns.distplot(..., ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(8))
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks()*20000+40)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]